# Increment the position of a node based on the value of child node

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Here is my source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <ID>12345</ID>
        <Amount>$850.50</Amount>
        <CurrentPayments>2</CurrentPayments>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <ID>45678</ID>
        <Amount>$6500.50</Amount>
        <CurrentPayments>5</CurrentPayments>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <ID>12345</ID>
        <Amount>$3200.20</Amount>
        <CurrentPayments>2</CurrentPayments>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <ID>12345</ID>
        <Amount>$6500.50</Amount>
        <CurrentPayments>2</CurrentPayments>
    </Worker>    
</Workers>
```

- `Worker` with `ID` value `12345`  appears three times on the source file with same value of `CurrentPayments` i.e. `2`

When above file gets transformed, position value of `CurrentPayments` should get incremented based on the number of times that element `CurrentPayments` appears on the source file.

In this case, first occurrence of `Worker` with `ID` value `12345` should have `CurrentPayments` value as 3(i.e. the value of `CurrentPayments` on source xml is 2 incremented by 1 - first occurrence of `Worker` with `ID` value `12345` )

Second occurrence of `Worker` with `ID` value `12345` should have `CurrentPayments` value as 4(i.e. the value of `CurrentPayments` on source xml is 2 incremented by 2 - second occurrence of `Worker` with `ID` value `12345` )

Third occurrence of `Worker` with `ID` value `12345` should have `CurrentPayments` value as 5(i.e. the value of `CurrentPayments` on source xml is 2 incremented by 3 - third occurrence of `Worker` with `ID` value `12345` )

Desired output is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <ID>12345</ID>
        <Amount>$850.50</Amount>
        <CurrentPayments>3</CurrentPayments>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <ID>45678</ID>
        <Amount>$6500.50</Amount>
        <CurrentPayments>6</CurrentPayments>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <ID>12345</ID>
        <Amount>$3200.20</Amount>
        <CurrentPayments>4</CurrentPayments>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <ID>12345</ID>
        <Amount>$6500.50</Amount>
        <CurrentPayments>5</CurrentPayments>
    </Worker>    
</Workers>
```

I have tried using `position()` , comparing value of current node with child nodes of same element using xpath axes etc.. for e.g.  `<xsl:value-of select="count(//.[(following::text() = text())])+position()"/>`

Here is my current XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="CurrentPayments">


        <xsl:for-each select=".">
        <CurrentPayments>
            
            <xsl:value-of select=".+ position()"/>
            
        </CurrentPayments>
        
        <!--<CurrentPayments>
            
            <xsl:value-of select="count(//.[(following::text() = text())])+position()"/>

        </CurrentPayments> -->
        
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

please Can you advise as to how I can get this to working ? thank you

**Added below**

Martin Honnen's XSLT 3.0 solution works perfectly fine for above requirement. However, I noted that `CurrentPayments` may not be present for all `<Worker>`.In this case,  source XML would look like this(last node of `<Worker>` with `ID` `123458`doesn't have `CurrentPayments` and expected output should have element `CurrentPayments` created with a value `1`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <ID>12345</ID>
        <Amount>$850.50</Amount>
        <CurrentPayments>2</CurrentPayments>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <ID>45678</ID>
        <Amount>$6500.50</Amount>
        <CurrentPayments>5</CurrentPayments>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <ID>12345</ID>
        <Amount>$3200.20</Amount>
        <CurrentPayments>2</CurrentPayments>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <ID>12345</ID>
        <Amount>$6500.50</Amount>
        <CurrentPayments>2</CurrentPayments>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <ID>123458</ID>
        <Amount>$6500.50</Amount>        
    </Worker>        
</Workers>
```

I added a new template `<xsl:template match="Worker[not(CurrentPayments)]">` to have element `CurrentPayments`created with value `1`. Could you advise if this is the only option i have?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:accumulator name="worker-count" as="map(xs:integer, xs:integer)" initial-value="map{}">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Worker/ID"
            select="let $id := xs:integer(.)
            return
            if (map:contains($value, $id))
            then map:put($value, $id, $value($id) + 1)
            else map:put($value, $id, 1)"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="worker-count"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="CurrentPayments">
        <xsl:choose>
        
        <xsl:when test=".!=''">        
        <xsl:copy>{. + accumulator-before('worker-count')(xs:integer(../ID))}</xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Worker[not(CurrentPayments)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>            
            <CurrentPayments>1</CurrentPayments>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 3, I think this is a task for an accumulator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="worker-count" as="map(xs:integer, xs:integer)" initial-value="map{}">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Worker/ID"
      select="let $id := xs:integer(.)
              return
              if (map:contains($value, $id))
              then map:put($value, $id, $value($id) + 1)
              else map:put($value, $id, 1)"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="worker-count"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="CurrentPayments">
    <xsl:copy>{. + accumulator-before('worker-count')(xs:integer(../ID))}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In that code sample, an accumulator stores in a map the `ID` of a `Worker` plus the number of occurrences of that `Worker`, the rule for `CurrentPayments` can then simply access the accumulator.

Comment: Thanks a million. this works. Based on my source XML, it's highly possible that `CurrentPayments` element will not exist for all `<Worker>`. In that case,  `CurrentPayments` will need to be created with value '1'. Now that i made a change to the solution you provided by template matching `Worker[not(CurrentPayments)]` Could you let me know if that's the only way to do that? or any minor tweaks to existing code without having to declare another template. I just added my original question with new template solution that i referred.

Comment: Adding new nodes without having existing input nodes to match but rather having to check for missing nodes requires you to add an additional template with such a condition. It might be less code to use e.g. `<xsl:template match="Worker[not(CurrentPayments)]/*[last()]"><xsl:next-match/><CurrentPayments>1</CurrentPayments></xsl:template>` but your approach is fine.

Comment: Thanks again sir for all your help.

Comment: Could you please explain what does `/*[last()' do? Was this for copying root element i.e. `Worker' and it's child elements until very last element? And what does `<xsl:next-match/>` do? Is it for copying last element under `Worker' ?

Comment: @MAT0718, the step `*[last()]` selects the last element child of the `Worker` element, the `<xsl:next-match/>` applies the next (in terms of priority) matching template (i.e. in this case, with no template spelled out for that element but the identity transformation being declared, copies that last child element).